# Codeception Lumen API - 'Auth guard driver [api] is not defined' When making multiple requests in a single test

Tags: php, codeception, lumen, laravel-passport, lumen-5.3

I have an API I'm building with Lumen 5.3. For Authentication I'm using Laravel Passport (ported to Lumen via the [dusterio/lumen-passport](https://github.com/dusterio/lumen-passport) package).

All works well in Postman, and all tests pass fine with a single request. 
However once I make a test that has multiple requests I get the error: 'Auth guard driver [api] is not defined'. The guard is defined in my auth config, and as I said works perfect outside of this test case.

Example test:

```
    public function it_requires_users_password_when_updating_email(ApiTester $I)
    {
        $I->wantTo('Require password when updating email');
        $user = factory(\App\User::class)->create();
        $I->sendPOST('oauth/token', [
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => 1,
            'client_secret' => env('OAUTH_SECRET'),
            'username' => $user->email,
            'password' => 'password',
            'scope' => ''
        ]);
        $token = $I->grabDataFromResponseByJsonPath('$.access_token')[0];
        $I->amBearerAuthenticated($token);
        $I->sendPUT('users/' . $user->id, ['email' => 'bender.rodriguez@planetexpress.com']);
        $I->seeResponseCodeIs(422);
        $I->seeRecord('users', array_only($user->toArray(), ['id', 'email']));
        $I->dontSeeRecord('users', ['id' => $user->id, 'email' => 'bender.rodriguez@planetexpress.com']);
        $I->sendPUT('users/' . $user->id, ['email' => 'bender.rodriguez@planetexpress.com', 'password' => 'password']);
        $I->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
        $I->seeRecord('users', ['id' => $user->id, 'email' => 'bender.rodriguez@planetexpress.com']);
    }
```

The test passes fine if I remove the last 3 lines (everything from the 2nd sendPUT request), but once I include that, I get the error.

Any ideas?